# STF from VCO Signal Flow Graph

Tags: control-system, vco

I've been looking at this paper that uses a VCO for a resistive sensor readout and I'm rather confused about how to derive this transfer function they have from their signal flow graph.

[image]

[image]

In their work for the STF of the system, they included a term of z^-2 in their numerator and -z^-1 + Gcl*z^-2 in their denominator. A closed-loop transfer function takes the form of G/(1+GH) where G is the feedforward path and H is the feedback path. The values of Gff and Gcl here make sense but I am not sure at all how they came up with the values of z in the numerator and denominator. Could someone break down the steps taken to derive the STF they determined?

Paper for context:

E. Sacco, J. Vergauwen and G. Gielen, "A 96.9-dB-Resolution 109-μW Second-Order Robust Closed-Loop VCO-Based Sensor Interface for Multiplexed Single-Ended Resistance Readout in 180-nm CMOS," in IEEE Journal of Solid-State Circuits, vol. 57, no. 9, pp. 2764-2777, Sept. 2022, doi: 10.1109/JSSC.2022.3163284.